# how do i add text to image in c# or vb.net

Tags: c#, image, text

I'm an average Visual Studio programmer. I need a function or routine to add text to the button of an image not on it like I showed in the image
[image]

Ideas please.

[Edit]

- Am programming with visual studio
  2008, on winxp.
- The application is a console app.
- it will run on win2000 upwards
- i will save the result image after
  adding text to file

Comment: Which UI framework? WinForms, WPF, Silverlight, ASP.NET, or Windows Phone 7?

Comment: do you want the result in form of image? Or you want to display it in a frame or webpage?

Comment: i added more info, can you please check

Answer (score 17, accepted):

- Create a bitmap with the new size you want
- Copy the original image at the top of the new bitmap
- Write the text you want onto the new bitmap

Something like this: (untested)

```
    var bmp = Bitmap.FromFile("orig.jpg");
    var newImage = new Bitmap(bmp.Width, bmp.Height + 50);

    var gr = Graphics.FromImage(newImage);
    gr.DrawImageUnscaled(bmp, 0, 0);
    gr.DrawString("this is the added text", SystemFonts.DefaultFont, Brushes.Black ,
        new RectangleF(0, bmp.Height, bmp.Width, 50));

    newImage.Save("newImg.jpg");
```

Comment: i have not tested the code, but it should get me started. if i have questions, i'll contact you

Comment: Thanks it works ..............To clear one ting for other a new image will store in root folder.