# How to build a 8.5 x 11 inch "Poster" PNG or JPG from Text and Pics

Tags: windows-phone-7

I need to build a Poster (8 1/2 by 11) using data entered by the user and pictures and place that poster in the user's media library.  It looks like BitmapImage is the mechanism to build either a JPG or PNG image but how do I place text strings and pictures on the image in a grid/form fashion?

TIA,
George

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to place things in a grid ina  form-style, it might be worth building it up in XAML or in code and then using `WriteableBitmap` to render it to a bitmap.

You might find the following posts useful to achieve this:

- [WP7 Screen Capture On-Device](http://blog.aggregatedintelligence.com/2010/11/wp7-screen-capture-on-device.html)
- [Screen Capture on Windows Phone 7](http://blog.markarteaga.com/ScreenCaptureOnWindowsPhone7.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I see part of my solution here in using the WriteableBitmap to create the bmp and now see how to capture a screen, but that isn't what I'm trying to solve right now.  The pointer on the WriteableBitmap is part of what I couldn't find.

Answer (score 0):

For an example of combining images and text see [how do i add text to image in c# or vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587642/how-do-i-add-text-to-image-in-c-or-vb-net/4587670#4587670)

Of course, any image can be printed at any size, it depends on the quality you want.

Comment: And, the other part of the solution I was looking for is here in how to create a grahpic and then drawing on it.  Thanks!