# Creating fillable template for image

Tags: c#, template-engine

I need to design something that emails coupons as attachments. I have a set of images for each of the different coupon values - $10, $50, etc.

On these images there are fields for the coupon code, expiry date and customer name.

I need to define the field locations and manipulate the raw image to "print" information on it, then I can attach it to the email. I think a pdf attachment would also be acceptable.

I want to be able to store the coordinates of the fields for each type of coupon so that I can reuse and adapt it easily.

I have no idea where to start - what is the best way to design this? Are images the best way to handle this? What about other technologies like pdf, html templating, etc...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587642/how-do-i-add-text-to-image-in-c-sharp-or-vb-net

Comment: Good link; but isn't there a more professional way to approach it?