# Annotate - Image document - C#

Tags: c#, annotate

I have the following requirement

- Need to provide Annotate toolbar while viewing images documents ( TIFF, PDF...) to user
- User can update, erase text and add comment in image document and save the document.

I am looking for a free SDK to do this in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify the code below from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4587670/395659) answer to macht you´r needs, regarding saving the texted images you can refer to [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/1da1014b-a7d9-407d-8dc4-c914d158300d) article.

```
var bmp = Bitmap.FromFile("orig.jpg");
var newImage = new Bitmap(bmp.Width, bmp.Height + 50);

var gr = Graphics.FromImage(newImage);
gr.DrawImageUnscaled(bmp, 0, 0);
gr.DrawString("this is the added text", SystemFonts.DefaultFont, Brushes.Black ,
    new RectangleF(0, bmp.Height, bmp.Width, 50));

newImage.Save("newImg.jpg");
```

Comment: Hi It won't match with my requirement. My requirement is provide a toolbar to user to annotate pdf

Comment: PDF is not an image document!, annotating pdfs and images are two different things